# Insert Sql query not working with HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to make a simple insert into a DB with HQlL by using native SQL code.

It doesn't give any error, it just doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
public void AddMedicament(Medicament medicament) {
    System.out.println(medicament.getName());
    // open a database connection
    Session session = FarmacieHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    // prepare SQL insert command
    session.createSQLQuery("insert into Medicament(name) values('test')");

    // close the database connection
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
session.executeUpdate() 
transaction.commit();
```

before closing session.

Comment: also transaction.commit();

Answer (score 2):

I am not familar with Hibernate, but i dont see you sre running your command. You just create query and close session
 I think you need some statement to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use createSQLQuery this throw a native sql instruction

Your object table name is Medicament too?

Answer (score 2):

session.saveOrUpdate(medicament);
tx.commit();
 then it will insert if u r not setting the Primarykey, if u r setting the PK in the domain object then it will be updated.

no need to executeQuery in hibernate if you are using the Spring ORM.